# Disable output in subprocess call ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, call

I am currently using the following command in python to convert my .webm file to .ogg

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', songfile, songfile + ".ogg"])
```

This prints out a bunch of output which I don't require, But I cannot disable it using this command.

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', ' -loglevel quiet','-i', songfile, songfile + ".ogg"])
```

I get error

```
Unrecognized option '-log-level quiet'.
```

How can I disable ffmpeg output here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) docs says

> To suppress stdout or stderr, supply a value of `DEVNULL`.

so you might replace

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', songfile, songfile + ".ogg"])
```

using

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', songfile, songfile + ".ogg"], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Daweo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68404945/4177009) is worth looking at, but here is why your attempt did not work: Remember that there is no shell involved when you do `subprocess.call` (unless you explicitly ask for it), which means that you need to pass `-loglevel quiet` as two separate items; `..., '-loglevel', 'quiet', ...`